# CouchDB filtered replication with params

Tags: json, database, filter, couchdb, replication

I'm trying to setup a filtered replication in CouchDb:

The filter I use is the following:

```
function(doc, req){ 

   if(doc._id == req.query.myid){ 
      return true;
   } 

   return false;
}
```

To test the filter I make this call:

```
GET /people/_changes?filter=data/mobile&query_params={"myid": "1"}
```

- The name of the database is "people"
- The design document with the filter is "_design/data"
- And the name of the filter is "mobile"

And I get this as result:

```
{"results":[

],
"last_seq":126}
```

when I had to get the document with id equals to "1".

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: can you give an example of what your document looks like?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are asking for a filtered list of changes. Since there are none the result set it empty. Replication accepts `post` requests only. Check out the [example](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication) in couch db wiki.

`{"source":"http://example.org/example-database","target":"http://admin:password@127.0.0.1:5984/example-database", "filter":"myddoc/myfilter", "query_params": {"key":"value"}}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
GET /people/_changes?filter=data/mobile&myid="1"
```

The query_params object contains all params you set via `GET`. Probably also `myid=1` would work, but I'm not quite sure.

Hope this helps!